# Minimize the following term under the given constraint

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ is a real valued continuous and differentiable function in $[0, 1]$ and $\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f(x)dx = 0$ minimize $\frac{\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)^2 dx}{(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx)^2}$

Comment: What is the source of this problem? I just answered essentially the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2985972/59379) yesterday...

Comment: Ah, it was a problem from an online contest which ended an hour ago... 
But anyways, thanks for the help